# Unable to rdp after fw change

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, firewall, windows-server-2012-r2

VM Windows Server 2012 r2

I was able to rdp to this PC without issues until today.

While logged in via rdp I was in *control panel > firewall* and I noticed that there was a message saying *'use recommended settings'* for the firewall - see below;

[image]

I clicked this, and the screen froze shortly afterwards. I was booted from the session and haven't been able to rdp since.

Whenever I try to rdp I receive the following error;

[image]

From what I understand this VM is one of many installed on a physical server. Controlled via vSphere.

The VM is on the same network as my office PC, I am able to ping the VM IP address. It's in a different location physically so I don't have access to re-boot anything.

- What should I do in this situation?
- Do I need to contact the server administrator and ask for a reboot of this single VM?

Comment: Why was this marked down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you changed the firewall settings, the server will maintain these settings even after a restart. From the host of this vm you can still connect and resolve your firewall settings.

So assuming you don't have access to the host of the vm ask the server admin to change the firewall accordingly for you.

Comment: Thanks @davejal this sounds like good advice. Why was this voted down?

Comment: not sure, but if it helped you can mark it as answer

Comment: Will do @davejal  No worries my question was also marked down - no idea why!

Comment: @johnny_s: Because pressing buttons you don't understand on a remote server you don't have other access to to fix is pretty dumb.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Some of us actually make mistakes. Please don't comment unless you have something productive to add. The question has been answered as you can see. Thanks.

Comment: @johnny_s: You asked a question. If you didn't want an answer, don't ask.

Comment: common guys, not here please